# regex column name from mysql error message

Tags: php

I would like to regex out second '' from the following error message:

`Duplicate entry 'this_can_be_anything' for key 'I_want_to_grab_this'`

I'm working with php, but have really vague idea of how regular expressions work. Or maybe I should use something else instead of regex? any directions? ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward:

`preg_match('/Duplicate entry \'.+\' for key \'(.+)\'/', $s, $m);` and use `$m[1]`

`$m` is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(68) "Duplicate entry 'this_can_be_anything' for key 'I_want_to_grab_this'"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "I_want_to_grab_this"
}
```

Comment: @Philipp if it is an array starts with $m[0]

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$yourstring = 'Duplicate entry...';
if (preg_match("=^[^']*'[^']*'[^']*'([^']*)'=", $yourstring, $matches)) {
    echo "Found value: " . $matches[1];
}
```

This will, however, match any line with the format:

```
Something 'something' something 'something'
```

Not sure if you want that. If not, follow the [answer by k102](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090799/989169).